# Centering text as block inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm building a form which will be used to register users.

Actually I'm having troubles with the css, I'd like to center a child div inside the parent div but without success.

I've tried different methods and I read a lot here but seems that the other solutions don't fit for me.

I don't want to use `text-align: center;` because I don't want to have a centered text, just pick the text as a block and center it. It has to be responsive, I've tried % but I don't like how it looks on my browser.

CSS & HMTL:

```css
/* ---===### REGISTER PAGE ###===--- */
.registerPage1{
 width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
.registerPage2{
 
}
.registerPage1 ul{
 list-style: none;
}
div#regMailError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regPLenError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regPMatchError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regCondError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
```

```html
<section class="registerPage1">
 <section class="registerPage2">
  <form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="" id="regTopfit" name="regTopfit">
   <ul>
    <li>Nombre:</li>
    <li><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellidos"></li>
    <li><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Dirección de e-mail"></li>
    <li><div id="regMailError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li>Crear contraseña:</li>
    <li><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="6-20 caracteres" ></li>
    <li><div id="regPLenError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Repite la contraseña" ></li>
    <li><div id="regPMatchError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="offers" value="Yes">Quiero recibir las últimas novedades de <a href="#">TopFIT</a></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="accepted" >He leído y acepto la <a href="#">política de privacidad</a>.</li>
    <li><div id="regCondError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Crea tu cuenta"></li>
   </ul>
  </form>
 </section>
</section>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `max-width`, and `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` for the child div. When the viewport goes beyond the `max-width`, the child div will center inside the parent div. (This is assuming you only want horizontal centering)

Add the following CSS declarations to `.registerPage2`:

```
.registerPage2 {
    max-width: 350px; // Set your custom max-width value
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here’s a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/vjsnrp4h/

Answer (score 0):

By default the second div was taking 100%. It was centered but still no place for margin because 100% width.

```css
/* ---===### REGISTER PAGE ###===--- */
.registerPage1{
 width:800px;
    height: auto;
    background-color : red;
}
.registerPage2{
 width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color : pink;
}
.registerPage1 ul{
 list-style: none;
}
div#regMailError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regPLenError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regPMatchError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
div#regCondError{
 display: none;
 color: red; 
}
```

```html
<section class="registerPage1">
 <section class="registerPage2">
  <form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="" id="regTopfit" name="regTopfit">
   <ul>
    <li>Nombre:</li>
    <li><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellidos"></li>
    <li><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Dirección de e-mail"></li>
    <li><div id="regMailError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li>Crear contraseña:</li>
    <li><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="6-20 caracteres" ></li>
    <li><div id="regPLenError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Repite la contraseña" ></li>
    <li><div id="regPMatchError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="offers" value="Yes">Quiero recibir las últimas novedades de <a href="#">TopFIT</a></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="accepted" >He leído y acepto la <a href="#">política de privacidad</a>.</li>
    <li><div id="regCondError">Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida.</div></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Crea tu cuenta"></li>
   </ul>
  </form>
 </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

.child-div{ margin:0 auto; }

.parent-div{ line-height: EQUAL TO DIV HEIGHT }

You will get vertical and horitzontal alignment.